# Gravar coluna array ou vários registros?

Tags: php, mysql

estou em dúvida de qual a melhor opção no quesito desempenho/performance na leitura dos dados. Visando uma com muitos registros e sendo acessada o tempo todo.

Preciso especificar quais bairros o cliente atende, ou seja, um cliente para vários ID's de bairros, é melhor fazer...

Exemplos da Estrutura do banco

Cliente | Bairros

1005 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 (ColunaArray)

OU

1005 | 1

1005 | 2

1005 | 3

...

Comment: Esses valores inteiros referente aos bairros são ids? Se sim, isso está parecendo que é uma relação muitos para muitos, tendo três tabelas: clientes, bairros e a tabela de relação. Preocupe-se com performance nesse nível apenas se identificar um gargalo na sua aplicação. Caso contrário, faça o que fizer mais sentido;

Comment: Eu iria optar pelo segundo em todos os casos, acho difícil o primeiro valer apena em alguma ocasião. Você pode querer fazer uma pesquisa por bairro. Por exemplo, qual cliente atende bairro "3", isso seria extremamente lento no primeiro caso, que iria ter que usar um `LIKE` e não aproveitar nenhum index. Já no segundo um `"WHERE Bairros = 3" resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na primeira abordagem você está criando colunas multivaloradas:

```
Cliente | Bairros

1005 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 (ColunaArray)
```

Qual o problema desta abordagem? A grosso modo, toda vez que precisar buscar todos os clientes de um determinado bairro você terá que fazer um **like**, ou seja, uma busca genérica na coluna *bairros*, isso pode ser muito pior do que possuir "múltiplos relacionamentos", falo em termos de performance e de manutenção (manipulação) dos dados.

Achei um post bem interessante quanto a colunas multivaloradas em bancos de dados: http://rberaldo.com.br/usando-campos-multivalorados/

Na segunda abordagem, utilizando uma tabela para **clientes**, uma para **bairros** e uma terceira para manter o relacionamento do tipo **muitos-para-muitos** você remove este problema referente a colunas multivaloradas. Vantagens? Você terá tabelas normalizadas (*Primeira Forma Normal ou 1FN*), além de simplificar o processo de buscar clientes por bairros.

> Primeira forma normal (1FN) – Essa é considerada uma parte da
>   definição de relação no modelo relacional básico. Sua definição prevê
>   que todos os atributos de uma relação devem ter seus valores definidos
>   sobre domínios atômicos ou indivisíveis. Em outras palavras, os campos
>   de uma tabela não devem ser compostos ou multivalorados. Vejam abaixo
>   uma figura que demostra a normalização de uma tabela que não está na
>   1FN para duas relações.

Para maiores informações quanto as formas normais: http://www.itnerante.com.br/profiles/blogs/desmistificando-as-formas-normais

---

*É importante ter em mente que podem existir casos especiais onde colunas multivaloradas são necessárias, entretanto, sempre que possível seria recomendado evitar o uso desta abordagem.*